# Refactoring Import statements in Java

Tags: java, import

I have too many common import statements in many Java Programs in a common package. How to factor out import statements and make the code look small and tidy. Example:

**JavaProgram1.java** :

```
package commonPackage;
import javaPackage1;
import javaPackage2;
...
import javaPackageN;
....
[Code]
```

**JavaProgram2.java:**

```
package commonPackage;
import javaPackage1;
import javaPackage2;
...
import javaPackageM;
....
[Code]
```

Now what I want is, I want a function or a macro type of thing in Java in which using a single statements I want all the packages to be imported, So that I can use the same in all the programs in a common package.

Comment: why do you want to import all packages in all classes? why not just needed ones?

Comment: If you need to import that many packages chances are that your classes are bloated anyways. Thus I'd first check whether it would be possible to split your code into more reasonable slices (e.g. try to adhere to the single-responsibility principle). Besides that only import the classes you actually need. And finally, most IDEs collapse the import block anyways so it doesn't matter if there's only 1 statement or 1000.

Comment: Use ctrl+shift+o ("Organize Imports") in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is if the classes you import are in the same package.

Lets say you have

```
import org.foo.package1.X;
import org.foo.package1.Y;
import org.foo.package1.Z;
```

You can use * to import all the classes in org.foo.package1 like:

```
import org.foo.package1.*;
```

But in this case you will import all the classes in org.foo.package1 which can reduce readability a little bit

Answer (score 1):

First note: don't worry too much about it. This happens often, and your IDE will remove it from your display so you don't waste half your screen. Having said that, you can often easily make the amount of imports smaller

I assume you have to work on your code tree

- Keep in your mind not to make a class too big. Seperate the goals (concerns) into different classes, and use those extracted classes with their needed imports. That newly created class can be extended, and/or used, and the dependent classes of that new class will not be needed in the class it got extracted from.
- If class A needs class B, and no other than class A needs class B, then save class B in the same package, and you don't need to write (generate) an import for it.
- If (nearly) a whole package is needed for your class to import, you can write `import this.important.package.*` and all will be imported. Your IDE will probably optimize your imports though and rewrite this one line into several different imports and you're back to where you came from.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, you don't do that manually.

Any decent IDE offers means to do that for you (for example, in eclipse, you just type ctrl-o to organize your imports). So you simple accustom yourself to hit ctrl-o from time to time. Or if that is an option, you configure eclipse to organize imports upon each save. Such policies could be extended to also run the built-in formatter.

The idea is basically: you definitely want to use some sort of tooling here. "Organizing imports" is a task that you, as a human being do not want to waste a single second on.

The one other important aspect: make sure that all people that might have to modify your source code agree on that tooling - you simply want to avoid a change history that contains a lot of deltas, just because people are using different tooling here.

You could even go one step further, and use your build environment to do that for you (so that it happens really automatically, in the background), like with https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-imports